# Converting \$\mathrm{V_{rms}/\sqrt{Hz}}\$ to \$\mathrm{A_{rms}/\sqrt{Hz}}\$ with an associate preamp gain

Tags: spectrum-analyzer

I connected my SR780 (spectrum analyzer, with PSD setting, y-axis = Vrms/√Hz to a pre-amp (DHPCA-100) in low noise mode/full bandwidth with different transimpedance gain settings (10<sup>2</sup> - 10<sup>6</sup> V/A) and tried to probe across a resistor e.g. 390 kΩ. How do I convert the Vrms/√Hz to Arms/√Hz in this case?

Thank you in advance. I would greatly appreciate any reference material I could read to better understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Divide by the impedance.  Which is the impedance of the resistor in parallel with the impedance looking into the probe.